# Is it possible to add middleware to the Flutter Navigator?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have the following check if I have an authenticated Firebase user

```
if(await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() == null)
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, TheRegisterPage.routeName);
else
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, TheGroupManagementPage.routeName);
```

And I would like to get this check executed every time the Navigator is called to navigate to a new route. Is there something like middleware or another approach I could use to achieve this?

I did find the RouteObserver class at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html but I noticed that it 's didPush() is not async so I wouldn't be able to asynchronously check if I have an authenticated user before the route is pushed. I dislike the idea of writing a check for each route since they will all be the same. So is there a way to implement some sort of async middleware with the flutter Navigator?

Comment: One thing you can do to achieve what you want would be wrapping a `Navigator` in a custom, let's say `AuthNavigator`, and perform your checks from there. The drawback would be that you would have to call `AuthNavigator.of(context)` instead of `Navigator.of(context)`, would that be okay for you? If it is, I can post a sample implementation of such a behavior in an answer, because I had a similar issue that you have and that was the approach I chose to solve it.

Comment: That sounds great actually! If you could post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation of an app that you can run in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) of a wrapper around `Navigator` that you can use to push conditionally, that is, to check whatever authentication confirmation to need to navigate to a page or the other, depending on the authentication state.

Note that the `FirstRoute` is a child of the `AuthNavigator`. Change the condition in the constructor of `AuthNavigator` to false, and you will see a different navigation. Here the key is the `pushConditionally` method, and the ability to access it from the `context` the static `of(BuildContext)` method in `AuthNavigator`.

You can do all of the conditional checking `async`, you just need to replace my `someCondition` for your specific needs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation Basics',
      home: AuthNavigator(
        someCondition: true,
        child: FirstRoute(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            AuthNavigator.of(context).pushConditionally(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text("Third Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthNavigator(
      {@required this.child, @required this.someCondition, Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool someCondition;

  static _AuthNavigatorState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AuthNavigatorState>();

  @override
  _AuthNavigatorState createState() => _AuthNavigatorState();
}

class _AuthNavigatorState extends State<AuthNavigator> {
  Future<T> pushConditionally<T extends Object>(
          BuildContext context, Route<T> route) =>
      widget.someCondition
          ? Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()),
            )
          : Navigator.push(
              context,
              route,
            );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;
}
```

Don't hesitate to comment if you have any doubt.

Comment: No questions. Just implemented it and it works. The code looks great and is exactly what I needed thanks!